# Line network segment length

Tags: qgis, postgis, osgeo

I am looking for a way to calculate the segment lengths of a line network. I am probably missing just the right vocabulary to search for the best approach, so I guess asking here would be a good idea. I have prepared an image of what I want to achive: 
[image: Line network with segment lengths]

Please note that I am not interested in the length of each line, I know how to calculate that. What I want to calculate is the length between the squares, the intersections that is. Bonus would be to have the lengths towards the end points of a line.

I imagine that pgRouting is able to do that, but I'd prefer a solution without Postgis.

Is this already built into QGIS with the Network analysis library?

I am unsure what to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By processing 'Split Lines with lines, using the same layer
[image]

Comment: Nice, thank, you. But that would have a completely dissolved input layer as premise wouldn't it?

Comment: @Frank - No, not necessarily

Comment: I tried your approach with a "worst case scenario", OpenStreetMap highway data and it did work.